# Adding a historical directory to Git branch

Tags: git

So I've run across an interesting problem where I'm missing entire directories when checking out a branch from Git, looking at the branch history shows files from the directory being added and that they had never been removed. So at this point I think the problem is that Git doesn't add directories dynamically based on file path, and that they have to be explicitly added to the branch before files are added to the directory.

Is there an easy way I can add the directory before the files are added so that they're actually persisted to a checked out branch instead of quietly consumed by Git?

Or do I need to do something like check out a new branch from the origin branch before the files are added, commit the directories, and then merge that branch back into the origin branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that they have to be explicitly added to the branch before files are added to the directory.

That would be surprising, considering git doesn't add/reference empty folders.

You could add a `folder/.keep` in order to make sure the folder is added to the index, and then later add some files in it.

Comment: Then why are the directories and files missing? I'm using `git checkout branch` in my project directory to change branches, but while I get most code changes it neglects adding files unique to the branch.

Comment: I supposed they were not added/committed, or they were ignored by a .gitignore.

Comment: Brief update, apparently my IDE marked the folders I thought were missing as 'Excluded' from the project structure when Git added them.